# One pivottable from several datasheets with Powerpivot possible?

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I have an Excel-workbook with 12 sheets, all sheets contain between 700.000 and 1.000.000 rows. All sheets have identical column-headings.

I would like to make one pivottable with Powerpivot from those 12 sheets with data.

I have added all sheets to the datamodel, after that I try to make a pivottable by clicking Powerpivot > Home > Pivottable.
Although when I click a certain columnname to use as a pivot table field, my tables are still separated in the pivot table output.
Is there an option so that Powerpivot sees all 12 sheets as one table?

thank you!

Marcel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out this method

http://www.contextures.com/PowerPivot-Identical-Excel-Files.html

In your case I would recommend to use Power Query for merging data from all list into one table, because it more manageable and flexible way.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Append-queries-Power-Query-e42ca582-4f62-4a43-b37f-99e2b2a4813a?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Best regards
Artem Glazkov

Comment: Thank you Artem, i will try these solutions. I have currently solved it by making a vba-script which makes cross-sums of the columns.